# Pass logging information as arguments to a function

Tags: python, logging

I use a Python library that uses the `logging` module. However, I made my own `log` function that my script uses internally.

Here's the logging function I want to utilize:

```py
def log(name, content, swtch : bool = None, time = None):
    time = time or datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))
    if swtch == True or swtch == None:
        toPrint = '{1.RED}{2}/{3}/{4} {5}:{6}:{7}:{8} {9} {0.BRIGHT}{1.GREEN}{10} {0.RESET_ALL}{11}{0.RESET_ALL}'.format(
            Style,
            Fore,
            str(time.month).zfill(2),
            str(time.day).zfill(2),
            str(time.year)[2:],
            str(time.hour % 12).zfill(2),
            str(time.minute).zfill(2),
            str(time.second).zfill(2),
            str(int(time.microsecond / 1000)).zfill(3),
            'AM' if time.hour < 12 else 'PM',
            name,
            content
        )

        print(toPrint)

    log_txt = ''

    if swtch == False or swtch == None:
        file = open('log.txt', 'r')
        log_txt = file.read()
        file.close()

        with open('log.txt', 'w') as file:
            text = '{0}/{1}/{2} {3}:{4}:{5}:{6} {7} {8} {9}'.format(
                str(time.month).zfill(2),
                str(time.day).zfill(2),
                str(time.year)[2:],
                str(time.hour % 12).zfill(2),
                str(time.minute).zfill(2),
                str(time.second).zfill(2),
                str(int(time.microsecond / 1000)).zfill(3),
                'AM' if time.hour < 12 else 'PM',
                name,
                content
            )
            file.write(log_txt + text + '\n')
```

Let's work assuming that there's a logger named `some_logger`.

```py
import logging

log = logging.getLogger('some_logger')
```

Is there a way to, instead of printing to stdout, pass positional arguments (representing log information) to another function instead? (To clarify: A function that will call `log` with the required args)

Comment: please show us some code where you want to use that.

Comment: Ok, will edit! Thx for asking

Answer (score 1):

I found out you can use something like a [`Handler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler) object to do this. You'd need to define a subclass that implements [`emit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.emit). See the example below for a basic setup:

```
import logging

class CustomHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(record):
        log(record.levelname, record.msg)

logging.getLogger('some_logger').addHandler(CustomHandler())
```